# TestNG Programmatically use xml configuration

Tags: testng

I'm wondering how I can write a program to run TestNG tests, still using the testng.xml file. For example, how do I make a class that can do this:

```
TestNG ng = new TestNG();
//ng.setTests("testng.xml") or something similar
ng.run();
```

I've looked at the documentation, but it's not very detailed, so I'm not sure if this is possible. Obviously, the comment should be replaced with the actual code to use the testng.xml file.

Do I need to use the TestNG configure method? Or does TestNG already have a method that does this that I missed?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question as to why you would want to do this without actually using the TestNG runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are other options out there, but you could use:

```
TestNG ng = new TestNG(); 
String[] arg = {"testng.xml"};
ng.main(arg);
```

and that should work fine. It's the same as running TestNG from the command line with the xml file as the argument.

Comment: I've used this as a solution to a similar problem I'm having, however it cannot find my test classes when executed? even though if I execute it manually it works perfect, but when being executed this way it cannot find my test classes